# Difference between Arduino DUE and Arduino UNO when converting char

Tags: c++, arduino

When reading a CMPS 10 compass using I2C the pitch is contained in one byte
which is in the range +/- 90 degrees.

Using char to accept the result and converting to int  works well on the Arduino Uno with the printout showing positive and negative numbers which is what I need.

```
#include "FastLED.h"

#define NUM_LEDS 150
#define DATA_PIN 6

#define CMPS_GET_ANGLE8  0x12
#define CMPS_GET_PITCH   0x14
#define BAUD38400        0xA1


CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

unsigned char  angle8;
char pitch;
int intpitch;



void setup()
{
  FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, DATA_PIN>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  delay(100);
  Serial1.write(BAUD38400); 
  Serial1.end();
  Serial1.begin(38400);
  delay(100);

}

void loop()
{
  getAngleAndPitch();  

  Serial.print("angle 8: ");        // Display 8bit angle
  Serial.print(angle8, DEC);
  Serial.print("    pitch: ");          // Display pitch data
  intpitch = pitch;
  Serial.println(intpitch);


  FastLED.showColor(CHSV(angle8, 200,200)); 
  delay(10);
}
void getAngleAndPitch()
{
  Serial1.write(CMPS_GET_ANGLE8);  // Request and read 8 bit angle
  while(Serial1.available() < 1);
  angle8 = Serial1.read();

  Serial1.write(CMPS_GET_PITCH);   // Request and read pitch value
  while(Serial1.available() < 1);
  pitch = Serial1.read();

}
```

On the Arduino DUE negative numbers of  -1 to -90 are 255 to 165

Is this documented somewhere and how do I get the correct negative numbers without resorting to an IF statement?

Comment: It outputs a signed byte (char). You don't provide the code for Arduino DUE but I'm willing to bet you are printing it as an unsigned char. Learn more about signed integer representation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations).

Comment: I have edited the code in the question to show the whole sketch which is used in both the UNO and DUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standard does not specify if the `char` type is signed or unsigned. It appears in your case that UNO uses signed chars, but the Due uses unsigned chars.

You can specify the signedness of your variable directly:

```
signed char pitch;
```

Or, you could use the fixed-length integer typedefs (found in the [`<cstdint>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) header):

```
int8_t pitch;
```

Generally, you should prefer to use the exact-width types unless you have a good reason not to.